# How to write a loop in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, loops, command

I want to have a loop of one line code in command line. 'FLAKE' is the model name and 'final.nml'is the file I want to input. Here is the code:

```
`FLAKE final.nml`
```

I only need to change the file number and export the new files. For example,

```
FLAKE final1.nml
FLAKE final2.nml
...
Flake final3000.nml
```

How could I do that? Because I need to import three thousands files, how could I write the loop in windows command line? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `For` Command in cmd.

```
For /L %f (1,1,3000) Do FLAKE final%f.nml
```

If you use this loop in batch, you must change `%f` to `%%f` (doble percent sign).